# ¿Guardar en ubicación seleccionada con JFileChooser?

Tags: java, java-swing

estoy creando un proyecto en el que guardo el contenido de un textArea en un fichero y para "guardar como" (la opción de menú) uso un JFileChooser en el que muestro un saveDialog, pero no consigo hacer que este, guarde en la ubicación que yo le indico. Me guarda el fichero con el nombre que le digo, pero en la ubicación del proyecto. ¿Alguien me ilumina? adjunto código del método que guarda.

public void guardarComo(){

```
    JFileChooser guardar = new JFileChooser();
    guardar.showSaveDialog(null);
    guardar.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);
    File archivo = guardar.getSelectedFile();
    File ruta = guardar.getCurrentDirectory();

    String nombre = guardar.getSelectedFile().getName();

    entradaSalida.guardarFichero(jtaConsulta.getText(), nombre, ruta);

}


public void guardarFichero(String cadena, String nombre, File ruta){

    File archivo = new File(nombre);
    FileWriter escribir;
    try {

        escribir = new FileWriter(archivo, true);
        escribir.write(cadena);
        escribir.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al guardar, ponga nombre al archivo");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al guardar, en la salida");
    }
```

un saludo y gracias

Comment: Saludos, David, el método `entradaSalida.guardarFichero(...)` ¿qué acción realiza?

Comment: @C.Rodriguez acabo de poner el método en mi pregunta. gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

---

Saludos, David.

Lo que pasa es que al momento de guardar el archivo (lo cuál lo realizas en el método `entradaSalida.guardarFichero`), le estás pasando **el nombre del archivo** y no estás usando **la ruta** correcta.

Si te das cuenta, `File archivo = guardar.getSelectedFile();` ya está obteniendo la ruta del archivo que vas a crear. Así que podrías acortar el código así:

```
public void guardarComo(){

    JFileChooser guardar = new JFileChooser();
    guardar.showSaveDialog(null);
    guardar.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_AND_DIRECTORIES);

    File archivo = guardar.getSelectedFile();

    entradaSalida.guardarFichero(jtaConsulta.getText(), archivo);

}
```

Y el método guardarFichero quedaría así:

```
public void guardarFichero(String cadena, File archivo){

    FileWriter escribir;
    try {

        escribir = new FileWriter(archivo, true);
        escribir.write(cadena);
        escribir.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al guardar, ponga nombre al archivo");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al guardar, en la salida");
    }
}
```

Comment: mil millones de gracias, que tontería... XDD. de nuevo gracias, era la primera vez que usaba un filechooser para guardar

Comment: En adición, el método `getCurrentDirectory()` retorna el directorio que se mostrará abierto en la ventana del dialogo donde se seleccionan los archivos y directorios. Por ejemplo, si queremos que cuando llamemos a `showSaveDialog()` se muestre el contenido de la raíz de la partición `D:` (en Windows), podemos hacerlo utilizando el método `setCurrentDirectory("D:\\")`. Este método es la contraparte  de `getCurrentDirectory()`.